# How to fix dependency mismatch?

Tags: java, struts2, dependencies, mismatch

I'm trying to upgrade struts from version 2.1 to 2.5 in my project. Although I added all the required dependencies in struts .zip file, it is not working properly. I suspect some kind of version mismatch in Spring or something else. How to solve this? Is there any kind of tools available?

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: you need to add more information to this like what are the dependencies you added where you added and the error you are getting etc.

Comment: Tomcat is working without any error. But gets 404 error. And I'm using Ant

Comment: How to resolve? Figure out the correct dependencies--but it's better to use a tool than struggling through by hand. Even relatively simple Java apps using any sort of framework have a fairly complex set of transitive dependencies. Without any usable information it's impossible to help.

Comment: *Is there any kind of tools available?* - Brain and a pair of hands (preferably connected with aforementioned brain).

Comment: Upgrading from 2.1 to 2.5 is a big step will cause a lot of errors. Read [release notes](https://struts.apache.org/docs/migration-guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools that let you manage dependencies in Java: Gradle, Maven en Ant are most well-known. Each of them will help you solve your problem, though Ant is perhaps least favoured lately. There is ample information on them available when you search for it.